# jUnit with two methods fails

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I have a test class with two methods annotated as @Test.

If i run each methods individually by commenting the other, it succeeds. But if run both together, it fails. What could be the reason?

```
public class ProductAvailTest {
private static final String PRODUCT_AVAIL_BUILDER = "ProductAvailBuilder";


@Test
public void productAvailResponseDateRequired() throws Exception {

    ResponseBuilderFactory responseBuilderFactory = ResponseBuilderFactory.createResponseBuilderFactory();
    ResponseBuilder responseBuilder = responseBuilderFactory.createResponseBuilder(PRODUCT_AVAIL_BUILDER);
    ProductAvailDateRqdHelper productAvailDateRqdHelper = new ProductAvailDateRqdHelper();
    List<Rsproducts> products = productAvailDateRqdHelper.getLOMProducts();

    // TODO change this to logger
    System.out.println("No. of products in test " + products.size());

    GetProductAvailOutput actualProductAvailOutput = (GetProductAvailOutput) responseBuilder.buildSuccessResponse(
            products, productAvailDateRqdHelper.getProductAvailInput());
    GetProductAvailOutput expectedProductAvailOutput = productAvailDateRqdHelper.getProductAvailOutput();

    // TODO change this to logger
    System.out.println("Size in expected " + expectedProductAvailOutput.getProductBrand().size());
    System.out.println("Size in actual " + actualProductAvailOutput.getProductBrand().size());

    Assert.assertEquals(expectedProductAvailOutput, actualProductAvailOutput);

}


@Test
public void productAvailResponseInvBased() throws Exception {
    ResponseBuilderFactory responseBuilderFactory = ResponseBuilderFactory.createResponseBuilderFactory();
    ResponseBuilder responseBuilder = responseBuilderFactory.createResponseBuilder(PRODUCT_AVAIL_BUILDER);
    ProductAvailInvHelper productAvailInvHelper = new ProductAvailInvHelper();
    List<Rsproducts> products = productAvailInvHelper.getLOMProducts();

    // TODO change this to logger
    System.out.println("No. of products in test " + products.size());

    System.out.println("No of inventory " + products.get(0).getRsproddtls().size());


    GetProductAvailOutput actualProductAvailOutput = (GetProductAvailOutput) responseBuilder.buildSuccessResponse(
            products, productAvailInvHelper.getProductAvailInput());
    GetProductAvailOutput expectedProductAvailOutput = productAvailInvHelper.getProductAvailOutput();

    // TODO change this to logger
    System.out.println("Size in expected " + expectedProductAvailOutput.getProductBrand().size());
    System.out.println("Size in actual " + actualProductAvailOutput.getProductBrand().size());


    Assert.assertEquals(expectedProductAvailOutput, actualProductAvailOutput);
}




@Test
public void productAvailResponseFreeSell() throws Exception {

    ResponseBuilderFactory responseBuilderFactory = ResponseBuilderFactory.createResponseBuilderFactory();
    ResponseBuilder responseBuilder = responseBuilderFactory.createResponseBuilder(PRODUCT_AVAIL_BUILDER);
    ProductAvailFreeSellHelper productAvailFreeSellHelper = new ProductAvailFreeSellHelper();
    List<Rsproducts> products = productAvailFreeSellHelper.getLOMProducts();

    // TODO change this to logger
    System.out.println("No. of products in test " + products.size());

    GetProductAvailOutput actualProductAvailOutput = (GetProductAvailOutput) responseBuilder.buildSuccessResponse(
            products, productAvailFreeSellHelper.getProductAvailInput());
    GetProductAvailOutput expectedProductAvailOutput = productAvailFreeSellHelper.getProductAvailOutput();

    // TODO change this to logger
    System.out.println("Size in expected " + expectedProductAvailOutput.getProductBrand().size());
    System.out.println("Size in actual " + actualProductAvailOutput.getProductBrand().size());

    Assert.assertEquals(expectedProductAvailOutput, actualProductAvailOutput);

}
```

}

Comment: helios, i have added the code. Problem is if I reverse the sequence, say i put productAvailResponseFreeSell() before productAvailResponseInvBased() then the test fails. Whereas if i put it as in the sequence above it succeeds. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would hazard a guess that the test methods are not setting up their environment independently.  So the first test within a given `java` invocation works, but leaves the environment in a different state that's not suitable for the next test run.

If you're setting up important state within static initialiser blocks, or possibly within the constructor of the test, you may fall foul of this.  Important state should be initialised either as local variables within the test method, or via methods annotated with `@Before`.

You should expand on what "it fails" means - is it the second of the two tests that fails by any chance, while the first to run succeeds?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you did something like this:

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;


public class StatefulTest {

    private static boolean shouldSucceed = true;

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        System.out.println("shouldSucceed=" + shouldSucceed);
        Assert.assertTrue(shouldSucceed);
        shouldSucceed = false;
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() {
        System.out.println("shouldSucceed=" + shouldSucceed);
        Assert.assertTrue(shouldSucceed);
    }
}
```

The first test alters some state affecting the second test. In this case a static field, but it might also be file contents or a bean in a re-used Spring context.

Comment: I think that's exactly what I did. I had few statics and it kind of created problems. Thanks.

Comment: not exactly. Because if u see the code i have posted, it doesn't have any static

Comment: Does GetProductAvailOutput have its own equals and hashCode implementation? You are asserting equals on instances of this class, and if they default to Object.equals this will fail for distinct instances, even if they have the same data values. I would start off by not using assertEquals on the instances, but compare the relevant data fields one by one.

Comment: You are using a static call to ResponseBuilderFactory to obtain a ResponseBuilder. Maybe the factory re-uses the ResponseBuilder instance created on the first call for subsequent tests?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible each state changes system's state (DB or some static fields etc) but not clear it in `@After` method properly?

Answer (score 0):

Probably some data shared between these two methods that is not reinitialized in a method annotated with `@Before`.

Answer (score 0):

JUnit Tests work very very very different than a "normal" developer would think. It is strongly adviced to read the JUnit documentation.

If you have a JUnit test with two @Test methods, the following is happening:
o  an object of your TestClass is created
o  the first test method is called

o  another object is created (so every instance field the first method has changed is lost now)
o   the second test method is called

This is not a "bug" but a design feature ... in other words the inventors wanted it like that. If you are new to such tools like JUnit, then consider TestNG, in the long run it might be more usefull to you.